# L equivalence classes

Tags: discrete-mathematics, dfa

Let L be the language consisting of all strings in (a+b)* that have an even number of letters and do not have aaba as a substring.

Into how many L-equivalence classes is (a+b)* divided?

Answer (score 1):

Construct the minimal DFA for the language L (this can be done by first constructing an NFA and then converting it to DFA because making an NFA is easier).

The number of states in the DFA is the number of equivalence classes the language L can be divided into.